# React-Redux large custom data-table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

I'm having some performance issues with react-redux in electron and large data table. I've done my own custom table which looks like this:

```
<Table>
 <TableHead>
  <tr> 
   x*<Column />
  </tr>
 <TableHead/>
 <TableBody>
  x*<Row> x*<TableCell /><Row />
 <TableBody/>
<Table />
```

My Table contains up to 20 Columns and 5000 Rows. I get updates every few secounds. I just made some time messurment with 13 Columns and 5000 Rows. Started at the Point Data comes in, until the view with the table is rendered it takes ~30sec. Which in my options is way to long.

```
export default class TableBody extends React.Component{

    eachRow(key, i){
        return(
                <Row 
                key = {i}
                id = {key}
                tableRow = {this.props.state.tableBody.byKey[key]}
                tableHead = {this.props.state.tableHead}
                />
            )
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <tbody>
                {this.props.state.tableBody.allKeys.map(this.eachRow.bind(this))}
            </tbody>
            )
    }
}
```

The array it's mapping can contain 5000 entries.

```
export default class Row extends React.Component{

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        return this.props !== nextProps
    }

    eachCell(col,i){
        const {
            tableHead,
            tableRow
        } = this.props

        return(
                <Cell 
                key={i}
                visibility = {tableHead.byCol[col].visibility}
                data = {tableRow[tableHead.byCol[col].name]}
                />

            )
    }

    render(){
        return(
                <tr>
                    {this.props.tableHead.allCols.map(this.eachCell.bind(this))}        
                </tr>
            )
    }

}
```

Each Row contains X amount of Cells, depening on how many Columns the table has:

```
export default class Cell extends React.Component{

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if(this.props.visibility !== nextProps.visibility || this.props.data !== nextProps.data){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    cellBackground(content){
        switch(content){
            case 'ENABLED': 
            case 'REAL TIME': 
            case 'REPLAY':
            case 'SENT':
            case 'ACCEPTANCE SUCCESS':
                //green
                return {backgroundColor: '#009900'}
            case 'DISABLED': case 'IDLE':
                //orange
                return {backgroundColor: '#ff6600'}
            case 'UNKNOWN':
                //blue
                return {backgroundColor: '#0066ff'}
            case 'ERROR':
                //red
                return {backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}
            default:
                //for every other cell dont use any styling options
                return {}
        }
    }

    render(){
        var cellStyle = this.cellBackground(this.props.data)
        if(this.props.visibility){
            return(
                <td style={cellStyle}>  
                    {this.props.data}
                </td>
            )
        }
        return null
    }

}
```

It feels slow for me, that my application takes 30sec to render 5000 rows. I have no data to compre my speed of my application. I think I'm doing something essentially wrong. Maybe there is a better way to profile where my app takes the time.

EDIT: 
I used the electron dev tools and profiled the performance of my app. The render Part takes 3190ms while the most time is consumed in the Scripting section with 36500ms. Somehow it takes a looooong time to create the childs and update their props or something. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I will try to make a version with react-virtualized and compair the time after it.

[Performance in electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8f1U.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I do not like the idea of render 5000 rows at once. Even a fast check on `shouldComponentUpdate` with each row will take a long time by multiply with 5000.

You can try to partition your rows by batches/chunks that fit your current view and fetch next by a button (e.g: press to load more ...)  or by scrolling down.

I would suggest [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same Idea that I only render what I see or something linke a infinit scroller that will add rows to my table view as soon as i scroll down. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I did some performance profiling and for any reason react takes around 90% of the time with scripting and not with rendering.

Comment: And it should be those times spent on `shouldComponentUpdate` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. If i send the first time 5000 Rows they are all new so i think it is normal that i takes so long?